# How to know the size (Number of nodes) of the tree built using Scikit-learn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, decision-tree

```
decReg = DecisionTreeRegressor()
clf = decReg.fit(X, Y)
```

Intuitively anyone would expect either decReg or calf should have a function which will return the number of nodes in the tree grown. But, I am unable to see any such function. Is there anything else to know the tree size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html), there's `tree_` attribute, you can traverse that tree to find any properties of interest. In particular, `children_right` and `children_left` properties seem to be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. But, could you please tell me where you got children_left, children_right information from? I think the page you referred does not contain that.

Comment: @happy_coder, I got it from the interpreter. I believe calling `dir` on a `tree_` will help.

Comment: Thanks again! Can I know which interpreter you use?

Comment: @happy_coder, sure. I use ipython — it has some syntax highlighting and auto-completion (on tab).

Answer (score 4):

```
# Instantiate a decision tree
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()

# Fit the decision tree
...

# Print node count
print(clf.tree_.node_count)
```